# Problema ao verificar dado em tabela SQL

Tags: php

Tenho o banco de dados ragnarok com a tabela login que tem o userid (usuario) e a user_pass (senha) da pessoa.
Estou tentando fazer com que o sistema entre nessa tabela e verifique se o campo digitado no formulario confere com o que está na database, porém, o php está retornando sempre como se eu tivesse diigtado o campo incorreto, sendo que eu estou digitando corretamente...

Código php:

```
$query = "SELECT 'user_pass' FROM `login` WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION["userid"]."'  ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    $campo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    if($campo)
    {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Senha atual errada!</div>";
    }
```

Não sei mais o que fazer..

Comment: Tente assim: `$user = $_SESSION["userid"]; $query = "SELECT user_pass FROM login WHERE userid = '$user'";`, lembrando que quando você usar aspas, para adicionar uma variável a string não é necessário quebrar ela; e complementar com o resto da verificação de senha, etc... é com você...

Comment: Você quer fazer um sistema de login? Essa query está buscando pelo id do usuário e não login/senha.

Comment: Luis, sistema de recuperacao de senha :x

Comment: RESOLVIDO! utilizei o código do @RafaelWithoeft. Estava dando errado pois eu utilizei na query SELECT 'user_pass' ao inves de SELECT user_pass. Muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram! Querem que eu faça uma resposta com o código correto?

Comment: @Guilherme seria interessante e marque-a como certa depois assim outros que acessarem poderão ver como foi resolvido.

Comment: Certo! Farei assim qur chegar em casa @Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei o código do comentário do @RafaelWithoeft. Estava dando errado pois eu utilizei a query `SELECT 'user_pass'` ao invés de `SELECT user_pass`. Muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram!